# why FullSimplify is needed here when Simplify alone should have been enough?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am not sure why `FullSimplify` was needed here.

```
ClearAll[x]
Simplify[x-Sign[x] Abs[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But

```
ClearAll[x]
FullSimplify[x-Sign[x] Abs[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In both cases, no assumptions are used. There are no special functions involved. There are no roots objects? No trig functions.

My question is, why `FullSimplify` was needed for this? What additional rules was used by `FullSimplify` which is not used by `Simplify` in this example?

Version 11.1 on windows 7

Comment: Because `Sign[z] == Exp[I Arg[z]]` is verified only by a transformation done by `FullSimplify` (for complex `z`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use FullSimplify, you can use use Simplify.

In:

```
Assuming[x \[Element] Complexes , Simplify[f[x]]] /. 
 Sign[x] -> x/Abs[x]
Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, Simplify[f[x]]]
```

Out:

```
0
0
```